# Regex beginner question - Number combination not found

Tags: regex

I'm using [RegexPal](https://www.regexpal.com/) to crosscheck my Regex.

I'm trying to extract phone numbers from text. German Phone numbers typically have one of the following formats:

```
0 0000 000000
+49 0000 000000
00000 000000
+490000 000000
00000/000000
+490000/000000
0000 - 00 00 00 00
+49000 - 00 00 00 00
0000 - 00000000
+49000 - 00000000
```

I have constructed the following RegEx to test the phone numbers

```
/([+]??\d{2}|[0])[\s/-]??\d{3,4}([\s/-]|(\s-\s))??(\d{2}\s??){3,4}/g
```

The last two layouts get detected, while the second last doe not. Could anyone explain this to me? Specifically the last space removes the last pair for some reason.

Edit:

```
00 00 00 00 vs
00000000
```

with this RegEx:

```
(\d{2}\s??){3,4}
```

The last one gets detected, the first one does not.

Edit 2: With (+49|0) I meant +49 OR 0. Replaced for clarity.

Comment: Try `/(?:\+\d{2}|0)[\ -]?\d{3,4}(?:[\ \/-]|\ -\ )?(?:\d{2}\ ?){3,4}/g`. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3D9cqB/1).

Comment: note in this case the `??` does no good

Comment: Every `0` is a placeholder for any digit?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes

Comment: Unfortunately, this still lacks focus. It will be hard for future readers to get something out of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your version with corrections:
`(\+\d{2}|\d)[ \/-]?\d{3,4}([ \/-]|( - ))?(\d{2} ?){3,4}`

1) Don't use `\s`. It also means the new line.
2) One `?` is enough.
3) `/` may need `\` inside `[]`. Not in browsers.
4) No need to use `[]` for only one symbol.

All your variants:

```js
console.log(`0 0000 000000
00000 000000
00000/000000
0000 - 00 00 00 00
+49000 - 00000000
+49 0000 000000
+490000 000000
+49000 - 00 00 00 00
+49000 - 00000000`.match(/(\+\d{2}|\d)[ \/-]?\d{3,4}([ \/-]|( - ))?(\d{2} ?){3,4}/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

reason is because of the `??` syntax
says match if can but ***preferr not to***

a good rx engin that is it is says ok then
only need to stop when in the quantified range and so it
doesn't have to match a space due to the `??`.

You'll notice if there is a space on the 3 rd time, the
engine will stop because it's met the minimum (3) and it doesn't
want to match that space.

See it in this example where this `(\d{2}\s??){3,4}` only matches this
 `00 00 00` 00
or
`000000` 00

[demo1](https://regex101.com/r/4mBJIX/1)

And the reason it matches `00000000` is there is no space
just before the last `00`.
It would match `00 00 0000` for that very reason too.

---

this `??` preference of no match almost always results in not
matching when it is the last sub-expression in regex.

so the engine really sees this `\d{2}\s??` as the sub expression that is
quantified. it only will match 3 times because `??` forces it to stop
after seeing a space before the last `000000 00` and meeting the minimal
3 in `{3,4}`

Steer clear of this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression for verifying the telephone numbers.

```
(?m)^(?:\(\+49\|\d\)(?: ?\d{4} \d{6}|\d{3} - (?:\d{2}(?: \d{2}){3}|\d{8}))|\d{5}\/\d{6})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h1s47i/1/)

I used the PCRE regex engine for testing, there's nothing fancy about the regex so it should work with most engines.

The regex engine performs the following operations. (I've put each space in a character class to make them more apparent.)

```
(?m)                   multiline mode
^                      match beginning of line
(?:                    begin non-capure group
  \(\+49\|\d\)         match '(+49|', 1 digit, ')'
  (?:                  begin non-capture group
    [ ]?\d{4}[ ]\d{6}  match ' ', 4 digits, ' ', 6 digits 
    |                  or
    \d{3}[ ]-[ ]       match 3 digits, ' - '
    (?:                begin non-capture group
      \d{2}            match 2 digits
      (?:[ ]\d{2})     match ' ', 2 digits in non-capture gruop
      {3}              execute non-capture group 3 times
      |                or
      \d{8}            match 8 digits
    )                  end non-capture group
  )                    end non-capture group
  |                    or
  \d{5}\/\d{6}         match 5 digits, '/', 6 digits
)                      end non-capture group
$                      match end-of-line
```